# What does "DECed" mean in Network Security?

Tags: network, ids, snmp

As in this MIB documentation: http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/F/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.php#fgIpsAnomalyDetections

```
fgIpsAnomalyDetections  1.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.9.2.1.1.9
Number of intrusions DECed as anomalies since start-up in this virtual domain
```

Comment: I read that as detected. The word Detections is right above it. But it is a dumb word to abbreviate, in the context of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most likely means "Decoded" in this context, as "decoder" is the language keyword [Fortinet](http://www.firewallshop.com/download/fortinet/FortiGate_IPS_Guide.pdf) uses to describe their anomaly detection:

> The FortiGate IPS uses **protocol decoders** to identify the abnormal
>   traffic patterns that do not meet the protocol requirements and
>   standards. For example, the HTTP decoder monitors the HTTP traffic to
>   identify any HTTP packets that do not meet the HTTP protocol
>   standards.

I would consider this a vendor-specific term rather than an industry term.

Another option might be "Decrypted", because Fortinet uses "dec" as their keyword for "decryption" (e.g., `set dec-offload-antireplay {enable | disable}`) but I truly think "Decoded" better matches the log entry you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was thinking it could mean "DEClassified", but now it seems to be the opposite!